# SELECT all orders with more than one item and check all items status

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables:

Orders:

```
Id   |  Status
-----+--------
 1   |      OK
 2   | WAITING
 3   | WAITING
 4   |      OK
 5   |      OK
 6   |      OK
```

And Order_details:

```
Id   |  Order_Id  |  Status
-----+------------+--------
 1   |         1  |      S1
 2   |         1  |      S1
 3   |         2  |      S1
 4   |         4  |      S2
 5   |         4  |      S2
 6   |         4  |      S3
 7   |         5  |      S1
 8   |         5  |      S1
```

What I need to do is to select all orders having more than one Order_detail and Order status must be 'OK' and every order_detail **must** have status in (S1,S2)

I've done something like this:

```
SELECT O.Id FROM Orders O 
            JOIN Order_details OD 
                ON O.Id=OD.Order_Id
WHERE O.Status='OK' AND OD.Status IN ('S1','S2')
GROUP BY O.Id
HAVING count(DISTINCT OD.Id)>1
```

But this returns all Orders that have more than one Order_details meeting criteria.

I'm sure that this part is fine:

```
SELECT O.Id FROM Orders O 
            JOIN Order_details OD 
                ON O.Id=OD.Order_Id
WHERE O.Status='OK'
GROUP BY O.Id
HAVING count(DISTINCT OD.Id)>1
```

But I must check if every Order_detail for above orders has Status IN (S1, S2).

So if Order will have 2 details and one of them has status=S1 and second S3 this order should be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT O.Id 
FROM Orders O 
JOIN Order_details OD ON O.Id=OD.Order_Id
WHERE O.Status='OK'
GROUP BY O.Id
HAVING count(DISTINCT OD.Id)>1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN OD.Status NOT IN ('S1','S2') 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select O.id
from orders O inner join order_details OD
on O.Id=OD.Order_Id and O.Status='OK' AND OD.Status IN ('S1','S2')
GROUP BY O.Id
HAVING count(DISTINCT OD.Id)>1
```

Comment: Won't this give the same result as first code from my question?