# Selecting Orders with multiple line items but not when one or more line items contains a defined list

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am having trouble with a SQL Server query. I have a couple of tables involved `[Order]` (I know, not named well) and `[Order Entry]`.

Order Entry is basically a "Line Item" on an Order (so there are one or more per Order). There are various columns in Order Entry, one of which is `ItemID` (there is only one `ItemID` per Order Entry). I want a query that returns all rows (Orders) that don't contain one or more Order Entry's with a list of ItemID's defined in a list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    oe.OrderID, StoreID
FROM 
    OrderEntry oe
INNER JOIN  
    [order] o ON o.ID = oe.OrderID 
              AND o.StoreID = oe.StoreID
              AND oe.ItemID NOT IN (60, 856, 857, 858, 902, 59, 240, 57, 217, 853, 855, 854, 41)
```

What I want to do seem similar to this (below) but I can't figure it out:
[SELECT all orders with more than one item and check all items status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052456/select-all-orders-with-more-than-one-item-and-check-all-items-status)

Help please! (much appreciated)

Comment: I doubt, Orders and Order Entry table share a primary-foreign key relationship so without an Order it's not possible to have an Order-Entry, so if there is an order then there should be at-least order entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to take a few pieces from several of you (Miguel Guzman - you provided the spark I needed to get this) and got it working. Here is my final Query:

```
SELECT o.ID, o.StoreID
FROM [Order] o
JOIN PSD_ServiceTicket st
  ON o.ID = st.WorkOrderID
  AND o.StoreID = st.StoreID
WHERE o.StoreID = 101
AND o.Time >= '10/1/2013'
AND o.Time <= '10/18/2013'
AND o.ID NOT IN (SELECT OrderID
         FROM OrderEntry oe
         INNER JOIN [order] o
            ON o.ID = oe.OrderID
            AND o.StoreID = oe.StoreID
         WHERE oe.StoreID = 101
         AND o.Time >= '10/1/2013'
         AND o.Time <= '10/18/2013'
         AND oe.ItemID IN ( 60,856,857,858,902,59,240,57,217,853,855,854,41 )
        )
AND (st.ServiceTypeID = 1 OR st.ServiceTypeID = 4 )
```

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want something like this.  Starting your query with the Orders table and using a left join will ensure that you get the orders you're looking for.  By left joining with a match on ItemID, you can then check for nulls in your where statement to find the orders that don't have those line items.

```
select distinct o.OrderID, o.StoreID
from Orders o
left join OrderEntry oe on oe.OrderID = o.ID and oe.StoreID = o.StoreID
    and oe.ItemID in (60,856,857,858,902,59,240,57,217,853,855,854,41)
where oe.OrderID is null
```

So to break this down a bit:

- "select distinct... from Orders" means "get me everything from orders"
- "left join OrderEntry on..." means "get me all OrderEntry records that meet this criteria; if no records meet the criteria, nulls are OK"
- "where oe.OrderID is null" means "I only want to see the items in Orders that had no match in the left join"

If we had used an inner join instead, we'd have lost that "nulls are OK" part, so the where clause wouldn't work.

Comment: This results in no matching records

Comment: I ran a version of this query on a similar set of tables in my database, and it worked as I expected.  Are you sure you have records that meet the criteria (orders with no entries that have one of your list of ItemIDs)?  Or perhaps I misunderstood your original question?

Comment: I think perhaps I didn't explain very well because this was not working for me, but I was finally able to resolve. THANK YOU for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT oe.OrderID, StoreID 
 FROM OrderEntry oe 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM [order] o 
                  WHERE o.ID = oe.OrderID AND 
                       o.StoreID = oe.StoreID AND 
                       oe.ItemID IN ( 60,856,857,858,902,59,240,57,217,853,855,854,41 ))
```

Is this what you were after?

Comment: This get's me the same result I already had...  I get all the same OrderID's returned (some of them contain oe.ItemID's in the "NOT IN" list)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select OrderId, StoreId
from Order O
where o.orderId not in (select OrderId from 
    OrderEntry d where d.ItemId IN (10,6,7,5) )
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT oe.OrderID, StoreID
FROM   OrderEntry oe
INNER  JOIN [order] o
ON     o.ID = oe.OrderID
AND    o.StoreID = oe.StoreID
GROUP BY oe.OrderID, StoreID
AND SUM (CASE WHEN oe.ItemID NOT IN ( 60,856,857,858,902,59,240,57,217,853,855,854,41 ) 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END) = 0
```

Comment: It seems like this is moving in the right direction. There is an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'."(I think because there is no WHERE clause here but instead an AND clause, but I think I don't understand something).

Comment: Here's the full code I have: `SELECT DISTINCT oe.OrderID AS OrderNumber FROM orderEntry oe JOIN PSD_ServiceTicket st ON oe.OrderID = st.WorkOrderID AND oe.StoreID = st.StoreID WHERE EXISTS (SELECT o.ID FROM [order] o WHERE o.ID = oe.OrderID AND o.StoreID = oe.StoreID AND o.Time >= '10/1/2013' AND o.Time <= '10/17/2013' AND oe.ItemID NOT IN ( 60,856,857,858,902,59,240,57,217,853,855,854,41 ) AND o.StoreID = 101) AND ( st.ServiceTypeID = 1 OR st.ServiceTypeID = 4 )`